# 7zip adding archive each folder using commandline

Tags: 7-zip, archiving

7zip command line.. 
adding each folder to new archive in one folder. please see the picture

I want to use the 7zip commandline

from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYAF.png) to [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ7vr.png)

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Basic usage of 7z command line is

```
7z a <ArchiveName> <Files or Folders to add>
```

example:

```
7z a MyZip.7z FileA FolderB
```

Can you be more details about what you're trying to achieve?